# Big Query Order By Grouped Field

Tags: group-by, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

I have a query that groups by date which works fine.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern')) date, SUM(users) total_users FROM `mydataset.mytable` 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern'))
```

but when I try to order by date:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern')) date, SUM(users) total_users FROM `mydataset.mytable` 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern'))
ORDER BY EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern'));
```

I get the following error:

```
SELECT list expression references column timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:35]
```

The timestamp column is clearly part of the group by and even stranger still is that it works without the `ORDER BY` clause... What's going on here?

Comment: What if you use `ORDER BY 1` instead?

Comment: still same error

Comment: I guess there is a bug in BIgQuery Sql, that you can not use expression in group by when you are having order by

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern')) date, 
  SUM(users) total_users 
FROM `mydataset.mytable` 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: you're on a roll with me :-) any idea what was happening? I'm assuming my use of names "date" and "timestamp" was a too liberal?

Answer (score 1):

You can try subselect:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  total_users
FROM (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp,'US/Eastern')) date,
    SUM(users) total_users
  FROM
   `mydataset.mytable`
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(date FROM DATETIME(timestamp, 'US/Eastern'))
  )
ORDER BY
   date
```